# Javascript class variables

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I have encountered an error while trying to declare a variable inside of a Javascript class. Here is an example of code.

```
class BaseContainer {
  constructor(parent){
    this.Shell = document.createElement("DIV");
    parent.appendChild(this.Shell);
  };
  this.SomeVar = 1;
};
```

It gives me an error.

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Comment: why is there a this reference outside any method in class declaration?

Comment: @binariedMe So i shoud not use this ? but will be this variable public ?

Comment: In a class declaration, you define variable without this context. and in method or constructor "this"is refered to the current instance.

Comment: Can you just write SomeVar = 5; and try?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you cannot declare variables inside a `class`. Put it in the constructor if you want to create a property. Also, you must not put semicolons after method declarations (including the `constructor`).

```
class BaseContainer {
    constructor(parent) {
        this.someVar = 1;
        this.shell = document.createElement("div");
        parent.appendChild(this.shell);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. also would like to know sisnce this JS classes are new to me. i always used old style function () {};  to do it. is this Class thing supported well now ? or it is still very new thing ?

Comment: @AntonStafeyev Only recent browsers do support them. For everything else, use a transpiler. For references, have a look at https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Answer (score 2):

Define variable without **this** keyword,

```
class BaseContainer {
  SomeVar = 1;
  constructor(parent){
    this.Shell = document.createElement("div");
    parent.appendChild(this.Shell);
  }
}
```